# How do I write a R script for patient data, that merge certain rows if a name appears twice, but keep values that are duplicates

Tags: r, tidyverse, merge-conflict-resolution

So far I have tried:

```
merged_data <- Mock_spreadsheet %>% 
  group_by(`pt name`) %>%
  summarize(notes_merge = paste(notes, collapse = ","), date = paste(`date of contact`, collapse = ","))
```

But I need to keep values such as contact info which is identical for identical names.

I would really appreciate any help!
The data looks something like this:
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH8gs.png)
I need it to turn out more like this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwoTA.png)

Comment: Please post a small reproducible sample of data within the question - 10-20 rows that demonstrate the data is ideal, along with the desired output for that sample input. You can use `dput(your_sample_data)` to make a copy/pasteable version of the data, including all relevant class information. You'll get help much more quickly if you make accessing your data as simple as copy/paste, rather than downloading some file and importing it, etc. It's also nice to make the question self-contained so it works as a reference for future users.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Give it a try.

```
merged_data <- Mock_spreadsheet %>% 
  group_by(`pt name`) %>%
  summarize(
notes_merge = paste(notes, collapse = ","), 
date = paste(`date of contact`, collapse = ",")
contact_info = contact_info) %>% distinct
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! It merges the data how i want it, but it returns with a duplicate, so Eva still appears twice with the same info in both rows. Any idea how to have only one row return for the merges data?

Comment: throw in a distinct in there